# You Do the Gallbladder, I'll Take the Appendix

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> Enclosure enclosing some music that’s acted.
> Another with snitch fore and aft is a note.
> A bird sound for every dinner extracted.
> Collaborate. Solve it. You’re done? Now upvote!

The answer is a single English word.

Comment: Don't tell me what to do.

Comment: @qwr Wait. Are you telling me what not to do?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you want an answer that will

> cooperate

Enclosure enclosing some music that’s acted.

> a **cote** is a structure to contain domesticated animals, surrounding **opera** the acted music

Another with snitch fore and aft is a note.

> a **coop** is another enclosure, with note **e** for and aft of **rat** which is the snitch

A bird sound for every dinner extracted.

> coo - bird sound, per - for every, dinner extracted - ate

Collaborate. Solve it. You’re done? Now upvote!

> Cooperate is to collaborate, and having cooperated solving it, will upvote.

Title: You Do the Gallbladder, I'll Take the Appendix

> Two surgeons who co-operate

Comment: Congratulations! You win... oh dear. Due to a shipping error, I am unable to give you the handsome plaque I had intended. In its place I seem to have the “Ace Pooter” trophy for excellence in flatulence and the “Pee or Taco” cup normally awarded to the contestant least able to distinguish between very different things. Neither being appropriate, I’ll have to catch you next time. Sorry.